# LWC/Apex JSON parse returning undefined

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I am writing a pretty simple lwc component that should display JSON data. The apex method makes an http call and gets a response. using the response.getBody method, this returns a string. My apex method declares a string, and the response body is assigned to that string. The lwc component calls that method imperatively and I assign that return to a `let` variable. When I parse it, to presumably change the string to json, I get object object. I have tried many iterations of this (which I will not post) such as stringify and then parsing, but it ends up with double json parsing. Here's my issue, when I try to iterate through that returned string (json) it is reading it like a string array, meaning , { data : [ id:001] } but returns ... => console.log(array[0]) => '}' . I need to be able to return the appropriate key/value pairs.

JSON

```
{
  "data" : [
    {
      "test1" : "079",
      "test2" : "00100",
      "test3" : "4352",
      "test4" : "543",
      "test5" : "234642",
      "test6" : 2719,
      "test7" : "hello",
      "test8" : "0444542",
      "test9" : "test hi one"
    },
    {
      "test1" : "24566134",
      "test2" : "0102",
      "test3" : "66543",
      "test4" : "244549",
      "test5" : "2666549",
      "test6" : 24525,
      "test7" : "once",
      "test8" : "595552",
      "test9" : "test hi two"
    }

  ]

}
```

Apex

```
        String jsonString;
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://fake.com');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        jsonString = res.getBody();
        return jsonString
```

JS

```
handleClick(){
returnVal({})
  .then(result => {
    let valJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result);
    }
    // JSON.parse alone returns [object object]. if I try to do valJson[0]. returns undefined
    // the current iteration valJson[0] literally returns '{'

}
```

Comment: Can you show the exact format of data which was returned from the backend to JS? Because the array was not returned from the backend so you can not iterate on it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fetch the values like this:-

```
handleClick(){
  returnVal({})
    .then(result => {
      let valJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
      valJson.data.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element.test1);
      });
  }
}
```

because **valJson** is having an attribute called **data** which is of **array type**. So you need to itearte on it find the values.

You were trying to do **valJson[0]** which is not valid.

### UPDATE

As per comment, method is returning stringified value, so slight change in above code. changed `let valJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result);` to `let valJson = JSON.parse(result);`

```
handleClick(){
      returnVal({})
        .then(result => {
          let valJson = JSON.parse(result);
          valJson.data.forEach(element => {
            console.log(element.test1);
          });
      }
    }
```

### Another Update

I have tried replicating your problem in my org. I created a method as below:-

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static string jsonReturn(){
        string value = '{"data":[{"test1":"079","test2":"00100","test3":"4352","test4":"543","test5":"234642","test6":2719,"test7":"hello","test8":"0444542","test9":"test hi one"},{"test1":"24566134","test2":"0102","test3":"66543","test4":"244549","test5":"2666549","test6":24525,"test7":"once","test8":"595552","test9":"test hi two"}]}';
        return value;
    }
```

then in my lwc js file

```
handleJSON() {

        jsonReturn().then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            console.log(JSON.parse(res));
            console.log(JSON.parse(res).data);
            JSON.parse(res).data.forEach(element => {
                console.log(element);
            });
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })

    }
```

and got this in log:-
[image]

Comment: this does not work. if i do console.log(result + valJson). it will show the full json data.  if i do a console.log(valJson.data) it shows undefined. when i declare that foreach if wont even run a console.log('foo) inside of it, because there is no elements for valJson.data.

Comment: ps: the above will only work and return [object object] for valJson if I remove the JSON.stringify and only leave the JSON.parse. with the stringify, it fails outright.

Comment: @sesanc, I corrected my answer.

Comment: as I tried to point out in my 'ps; this wont work. if i do a console.log(valJson.data) returns undefined. if i write the foreach and do a console.log('foo') inside, it wont print because there is no 'element' for valJson.data. **this is after removing the JSON.stringify

Comment: I've tried doing Object.entries(valJson).forEach(element) and it seems to be printing out a character array this way. my output is literally " 
console test object entries0,{ 
console test object entries1,"
console test object entries2,i
"

Comment: @sesanc please see the updated answer again. I have replicated the same problem in  my org.it works fine.

Comment: I dont know why yours works and mine does not. I think it may be due to the fact that yours is strinctly a string and mine is a response.getBody(). BUT, I was able to get it to work. if I do a valJson.data[0].test1 , I get the correct response. so my solution was valJson.data.foreach then a nested for..in. from there I can receive the key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Explination:
First we will parse the backend result
then we will itreate on  `valJson.data`

```
handleClick(){
  returnVal()
  .then(result => {
      let valJson = JSON.parse(result);
      valJson.data.forEach((d)=>{
         console.log('Record:',d);
      })
    }
}
```